# Media Queries help? - Desktops

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to target a desktop with the screen size 1944 by 1080. I do this the normal way..

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1944px) and (max-height: 1080px) {

 .about-section {
  margin-top: 600px;
 }
 .container h3 {
 position: relative;
 top: -200px;
 }

}
```

When I do this though, it affects my default resolution - 1440 by 900 -. 
I'm confused does this mean I will have to rewrite code underneath this query for my default resolution?

So I want the header to be in a different position when viewed on a larger screen? 
But I want the default header to not be affected by this?

I feel like I'm missing something, I know it cascades but surely the desktop query doesn't need to be at the top of the CSS file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-width` means it will affect any browser with a screen lower than that value.  If you want to target those dimensions *and above only* then use `min-width` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1944px) and (max-height: 1080px) and (min-width: 1441px) {   }
```

To target your code to only > 1440px wide.

however you should probably just use

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1441px) {   }
```

Comment: Yep I get ya! Thanks alot!